# Swipeable views in ios

Tags: ios, swift

There are two views in my screen. The first part consists of a map and the second part consists of a tableview. After dragging the tableview part upwards the tableview occupies the entire screen. How to achieve this in ios?

Comment: You should use `UICollectionview` tableview can't scroll horizontally

Answer (score 0):

First the bottom part should be a collectionView , second you can use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to detect user pan and update the origin Y of the collectionView